# Protecting hybrid apk

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security, apk

I have made hybrid apk using Cordova ( Javascript, jquery, ajax, css, html etc) and I am trying to hide / encrypt ajax call or else call will be abused (there is decompile apk online). Is there any chance to protect calling my php files from server with some tokens etc.. ?

Comment: Yes you should do some authen... let's say add a token (timestamp + valid session + ... etc)

Comment: @CKWong I did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make protecting api with implement oauth2 Authorization.

maybe it will be useful https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/